# web form doesnt call jquery library when its using a master page, but works without a master page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I'm trying to use the jquery library called "chosen" to make drop downs, and lists a lot better.
Here is the jquery library chosen: http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

If I just create a web form with this content:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="AssetTracker.Chosen.WebForm1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">  
  <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="../chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="docsupport/prism.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Chosen/chosen.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#DropDownList1").chosen();
      });
  </script>
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList CssClass="chosen-single" ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" data-placeholder="Choose one...">
            <asp:ListItem>USA</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Russia</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Poland</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

It works fine, I can call:

`.chosen()`

With no errors as well as a beautiful drop down list.  Now the issue is I have a asp.net web form that uses a master page like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="AssetTracker.Chosen.WebForm2" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="../chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="docsupport/prism.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Chosen/chosen.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#MainContent_DropDownList1").chosen();
      });
  </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList CssClass="chosen-single" ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" data-placeholder="Choose one...">
            <asp:ListItem>USA</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Russia</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Poland</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Same solution, same project but the one with the master page in the console gives me an error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'chosen'`

I know generally speaking this error is due to not being able to find the script file...but as I have said this is the same location, same solution, same project...But for the life of me I cannot get it to work.

If anyone needs here is the master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="AssetTracker.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Asset Tracker</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="HeadContent" />
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <%--Framework Scripts--%>
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
            <%--Site Scripts--%>

        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <header>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
            </div>
            <div class="float-right">
                <section id="login">
                    <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">

                        <LoggedInTemplate>
                            <p>
                                Hello, <a runat="server" class="username" href="#" title="">
                                    <asp:LoginName runat="server" CssClass="username" />
                                       </a>
                            </p>
                        </LoggedInTemplate>
                    </asp:LoginView>
                </section>
                <nav>
                    <ul id="menu">
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="body">
        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainMessageContent" runat="server"/>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ButtonContent" runat="server"/>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="MainContent" />
        </section>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This has got to do with something conflicting between the jquery libraries but I don't understand `Site.master` site master pages enough to understand why this is happening.  Please can someone let me know where I have gone wrong?

Comment: It looks like jquery is included both by your content page and your master page. Try eliminating one so jquery is only referenced once.

Comment: wow you were right so simple....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced this many times when using Master Pages. 
First, I think you should remove any reference to your Jquery library from you Master Page. 
Remember that when you load Jquery library more than once it stops working. So if you use this `<asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />` you are internally calling again the Jquery library, so remove this from your MasterPage. The goal is that you call Jquery Library only once to avoid this common error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'xxxxx'`. Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem that you have a relative path to the 'chosen' javascript file?

If the URL of the displayed page, on any particular page, doesn't have the same path, the `../` part of the path to the 'chosen' file will be incorrect.

Perhaps if you use a fully specified URL for the script.

Answer (score 0):

first make sure you have the javascript loaded then ...
the problem is because you are using a master page, it will change the client side id of your elements on the page

so you can use this for example

```
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">
```